# AngularJS - ngBindHtml and 'unsafe' html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to render some unsafe HTML (basically a HTML snippet with some inline styling) and have the following code in my view:

```
<div ng-repeat="snippet in snippets">
  <div ng-bind-html="snippet.content"></div>
</div>
```

All my styling gets removed...

I've heard of people using ngBindHtmlUnsafe however I couldn't find a reference to it and simply putting **ng-bind-html-unsafe** doesn't render anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What AngularJS version are you using?

Comment: You need to include the html string you're trying to use also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bypass it using  `$sce.trustAsHtml`  . See [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce#example)

```
self.snippet.content = $sce.trustAsHtml('some html');
```

Answer (score 8):

The `ng-bind-html-escape` was removed in AngularJs 1.2.

To achieve the same effect I would advise you to create a filter to trust the resource (you should include the [$sce module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce) ):

```
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    }; });
```

Usage:

```
<ELEMENT ng-bind-html="htmlValue | unsafe"></ELEMENT>
```

You shouldn't forget to include the ngSanitize as the app dependency:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
```

Cheers.

Comment: @Flek Hmm.. That's interesting. I said that simply because in the docs  regarding `ng-bind-html` it says: ["To utilize this functionality, ensure that $sanitize is available, for example, by including ngSanitize in your module's dependencies (not in core Angular.)"](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtml). But I guess if you have a escaped html you don't need to. Thanks for the info though!

Comment: Yes the docs confused me in the beginning as well. I just figured out that `ngSanitize`is not needed because I forgot to include it once and it still worked.