# IE8 AngularJS Page Load Lag + ng-bind-html issue

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

For context, I work in an environment where I still need to support IE8 (still the default distribution on computers); I am also using twitter bootstrap 3; Angular is latest version. I am returning data from APIs and using ng-repeat to build the results in the view. Anyone out there developing applications in IE8 land? All my stuff is working stellar in Chrome.

I have 2 problems.

One is that in IE8, loading of the ng-repeat-driven API results takes forever or never finishes. If I open developer tools in IE8 and debug, on the refresh it loads the ng-repeat results fine. This happens every time.

Here's the beginning of my :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I have no idea why that is happening. Should I be using a different  tag? I am wondering if IE8 Developer Tools loads items in a different IE8 mode than I have in the head. I am not clear on how I check the status of the API response in IE8 to verify that it is not a problem with the API call going out, rather than a problem of angular rendering the response.

The other issue is the ng-bind-html is not returning any values from certain fields of my API response in IE8. Working fine in Chrome. Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559070/angularjs-ngbindhtml-and-unsafe-html) a true alternative to ng-bind-html, and one that will work in IE8?

Comment: How many think the solution is to just junk IE8 support?

Comment: in addition, IE8 generates a bunch of '  Error: Unknown runtime error'. No idea what those are, and no idea how to drill down any further on those. No detail is provided besides an entry in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Stack Overflow won't let me answer or upvote the answer I found...[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559070/angularjs-ngbindhtml-and-unsafe-html?lq=1) provides the solution to the ng-bind-html. Wasn't clear how you could apply that via a filter until I saw the answer that was not selected.

As for the other issue, I am going to go the route of an API call that does not include a data body (the API I am using can have the data come multiple ways). Case closed (in so much as I can move on...still plenty of unanswered questions.).